# Large images are not resized in the moderator tools

Tags: bug, design, moderator-tools, images

Yesterday I reviewed a flag on [a question containing a large image](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/95756/can-i-reapply-immediately-after-a-uk-visa-refusal) via the moderator dashboard page. I noticed that images are not resized properly when viewing posts via this page:

[image: Large image not resized in mod tools]

Is this by design or is it a bug?

I'm running Firefox ESR 45.9.0 on Debian Wheezy (7.11).

Comment: Hmm. If something is working as designed, is it a bug if the end result is unexpected because the design is wrong?

Comment: @AndrewLeach that's called a design bug ;)

Comment: What do you mean by "reviewed a flag ... via the moderator flag-handling tool"? The right-hand sidebar you've got there looks like the one from [the mod dashboard page](https://travel.stackexchange.com/admin/dashboard) where you see pending flags, but your view of the question (including voting buttons and dupe banner) isn't how I normally see questions on the dashboard page. Are you running some userscript which gives you a more detailed view of flagged posts?

Comment: @Randal'Thor Thank you for that. I could not remember how that page is called. Indeed I meant the mod dashboard page. I am not using script on flagged posts. I am using the Show Comment Flagger script for comments. I doubt this script modifies the layout so much.

Comment: The only thing that prevents the images from overtaking the screen is [this single CSS rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sr4iN.png). Taking it away, I see exactly what you posted here. So either they forgot to add that rule in the moderator dashboard CSS (or using different class name), or something on your side is messing with the CSS. Need other moderators on that site to know for sure, you can also try with other browser.

Comment: I can confirm that this doesn't happen on Graphic Design (images have a `max-width: 100%;`)

Comment: @Randal'Thor you get a plain-text preview by default but clicking the little arrow to the left expands it to a full preview

Comment: @Cai OOOH. There's something I never realised! :-D